# Running Uvicorn with unix socket

Tags: uwsgi, systemd

I'm having trouble running uvicorn on a unix socket with...

I have tried the below plus every combination I can think of, both in the command line and in systemd Unit file as well...

`env/bin/uvicorn appname.asgi:application --uds unix:/run/uvicorn/appname.sock` and every other combination produces a `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`, but the directory is there...

Am I missing something here? I am not an expert in Ubuntu or systemd, but I was able to set up Nginx and uWSGI pretty easily.

Answer (score 11):

Well... as it turns out, it was much simpler than I though:

The solution is to NOT use the `unix:` prefix, only the location of the socket, e.g.:

```
venv/bin/uvicorn appname.asgi:application --uds /run/uvicorn/appname.sock
```