Reverse proxy for uvicorn not working when entering domain without port
It works with the : (example.com:9000) but if you take out the port, it doesn't work. Here are my configurations:
uvicorn.socket
[Unit]
Description=uvicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/uvicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target

uvicorn.service
[Unit]
Description=uvicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/uvicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target

[Unit]
Description=uvicorn service
Requires=uvicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/comp/service
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/comp/venv/bin/uvicorn \
            main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 9000 --reload

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

example.conf (NGINX config)
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/run/uvicorn.sock;
        }
}


It works because you access it without the nginx involved. You should listen for the loopback ip (127.0.0.1) instead of "0.0.0.0". But this solves not why "its not work". Check the logs and describe what/how its not work. "Its not working" is not precise problem. I think you need to tell your app/uvicorn to listenon a unix socket instead of ip/port: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52508005/5781499
